# How to implement nltk stopwords on python dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I have an excel file that contains 1000 line of text articles. I want to implement nltk stopwords (as i want to remove certain characters or words form being printed). How can i apply nltk on python dataframe. For instance: I don't want words like: a, nothing, were, the etc to be printed.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop = stopwords.words ("a", "about", "above", "across", "after", 
   "afterwards",
     "again", "all", "almost", "alone", "along", "already", "also",
       "although", "always", "am", "among", "amongst", "amoungst", "amount", 
                             "an",
                  "and", "another", "any", "anyhow", "anyone", "anything", 
             "anyway", "anywhere", "are", "as", "at", "be", "became",
                  "because", "become","becomes", "becoming", "been", , "ie", 
           "thereafter", "thereby", "therefore", "therein", "thereupon")

 df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\farid-PC\\Desktop\\Tester.xlsx')
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)#untruncate the unseen text
df[''] = df['Text'].apply(lambda  x: ' '.join([item for item in 
string.split(x) if item not in stop]))


frequency = df.Text.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()# counter
T = 4000000 
word_freq = frequency/T #frequency of the word occurrence in the document


print("word                     P(w)")
 print(word_freq)
```

Data File(excel file):
   Text
Trump will drop a bomb on North Korea
Building a wall on the U.S.-Mexico border will take literally years
Wisconsin is on pace to double the number of layoffs this year.
Says John McCain has done nothing to help the vets.
Suzanne Bonamici supports a plan that will cut choice for Medicare Advantage seniors.
When asked by a reporter whether hes at the center of a criminal scheme to violate campaign laws, Gov. Scott Walker nodded yes.

```
 Output required:
 word              word_frequency
 Trump               0.00256
  bomb                0.0076
  Wisconsin           0.00345
```

//the output shouldn't include the stop words or punctuation's or numbers

Comment: Can you share an example of your dataframe with desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 


stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 

def filter_stopwords( sentence ): 
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(example_sent)
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 

example_df.apply( filter_stopwords )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop = stopwords.words('english')
stops = r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(stop))

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Some text that I wrote',
                         'Some more text for you']})

df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(stops, '').str.replace('\s+', ' ')

df

#                   A
#0  Some text I wrote
#1         Some text
```

Comment: i added more detail to the question. Maybe it will explain my current problem

Comment: I'm basically trying to create a classifier that can distinguish between real or fake article. but i first need to filter the excel file form stop words, unnecessary punctuation